# How add menuitem in word in c#

Tags: c#

I have tried this code for add new menu item in word document on right click. But there is one problem

Error: 'this.Application' this line give an error of the statement is not in current context. What is the solution like any package is required for this line or any another solution.

```
Word.Application application;

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    application = this.Application;
    application.WindowBeforeRightClick +=
        new Word.ApplicationEvents4_WindowBeforeRightClickEventHandler(application_WindowBeforeRightClick);

    application.CustomizationContext = application.ActiveDocument;

    Office.CommandBar commandBar = application.CommandBars["Text"];
    Office.CommandBarButton button = (Office.CommandBarButton)commandBar.Controls.Add(
        Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton);
    button.accName = "My Custom Button";
    button.Caption = "My Custom Button";
}

public void application_WindowBeforeRightClick(Word.Selection selection, ref bool Cancel)
{
    if (selection != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(selection.Text))
    {
        string selectionText = selection.Text;

        if (selectionText.Contains("C#"))
            SetCommandVisibility("My Custom Button", false);
        else
            SetCommandVisibility("My Custom Button", true);
    }
}

private void SetCommandVisibility(string name, bool visible)
{
    application.CustomizationContext = application.ActiveDocument;
    Office.CommandBar commandBar = application.CommandBars["Text"];
    commandBar.Controls[name].Visible = visible;
}
```